# Classifying data inside mongodb using naiva bayes

Tags: java, mongodb, classification, lingpipe

I want to classify news in the `mongodb` database to certain specific categories using Naive Bayes.

My training data contains different set of news of the fields sports, arts, entertainment etc.
I have to train this data and build a model and then apply test data for checking its accuracy..  I have already done that which is showing good accuracy but the problem is that now I have to train data inside a database...
I have used [lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html) tool for that...

Now what I want is that my `mongodb` database has different sets of data based on each categories ...how can I train data inside a database...Is it possible???

Comment: Can you give me sample code for the same. as I am learning recommendation and working on mongodb , hadoop and mahout for this. my email is abhimanyu.mailme@gmail.com

Comment: @Abhimanyu Still now I didn't find a solution to train mongo database....but i have added a solution which I had implemented

Comment: @Abhimanyu initially I used naive bayes classification algorithm...but because of its poor accuracy....i have implemented my own classification algorithm which yields a better result than naivebayes...Better you implement yourself according to your requirements or search a better algorithm